# Debugging options are invisible

Tags: java, debugging

I have code I want to debug but my step into and over buttons are invisible. I set a break point but I can't click on these buttons. Keep in mind I am new, my dad said it's a simple fix.

Thank you!!

Comment: My guess is that the break point is never reached, so there is never anything to step into/over. It would help to see some code and where the break point is though.

Comment: You should start the program with the debugger to see those options or in the debug menu you should see them thus clicking on one of them will launch your program in debug mode. Assuming that the break point is reachable (No exception thrown before).

Comment: If you are using an IDE, which one?

Comment: I am using Eclipse

Answer (score 0):

Either your code has not reached the break point or any exception before reaching the Breakpoint or `Skip All Breakpoints` is enabled in debug panel, `Ctl + Alt + B` toggle that if enabled

[image]